# System not allowing me to ask questions on math.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, rate-limiting

So I got the wait 6 days before posting again issue on math.stackexchange.com: [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543)

The thing is I have only two questions asked, both with positive scores and accepted answers.

*But* I have one question that was deleted and thus there is nothing I can do to change it. Is this one deleted question triggering this?

I've been a member of stackexchange for years with only positive scores on all the sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this one deleted question triggering this?

Very likely. It is heavily downvoted, and was deleted close to being asked.

But don't lose hope.

Comment: I feel this is a bit unfair, there is nothing I can do about the deleted question and so I'm stuck for 5 days when I would like to post more questions.

Comment: You have to wait about 6 months